# How to sort an list first letter ascending and last letter decending in java?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list with values

- 1alfreda
- 1alfredb
- 1alfredc
- 2benb
- 2benc
- 2benb

I want the list to be sorted out as first letter ascending and last letter descending so the sorted list is

- 1alfredc
- 1alfredb
- 1alfreda
- 2benc
- 2benb
- 2bena

How can i do it in java ? Plz help.

Comment: Just implement your own comparator. But I think this order doesn't make any sense. What'd you do in case of `1alfreda` and `1alfreca`?

Comment: So you ONLY want to sort on the first and last letter? Nothing in between? 'ABA' and 'AZA' are to be considered equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested it, something like this, should work.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String e1, String e2) {
    int c = new Character(e1.chartAt(0)).compareTo( e2.charAt(0) );
    if( c!=0 )
       return c;
    return new Character(e2.chartAt(e2.length()-1)).compareTo( e1.charAt(e1.length()-1) )
  }
});
```

Comment: you should exchange e1 and e2 in the second compare, since last letter should be descending

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) and then specify the `Comparator` where ascending or descending.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Item>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String s1, String o2) {
    return s1.compareTo(s2);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It might look like this.

```
public FirstLetterComparator implements Comparator<String>{
    public int compare(String left, String right){
          String leftFirst = left.substring(0,1);
          String rightFirst = right.substring(0,1);


          return left.compareTo(rightFirst) && ;
    }

}
public LastLetterComparator implements Comparator<String>{
          String leftLast = left.substring(left.length-2,left.length-1);
          String rightLast = right.substring(right.length-2,right.length-1);
         return leftLast.compareTo(rightLast);

}

List<String> yourList = new ArrayList<String>();
Collections.sort(yourList,new FirstLetterComparator());
Collections.sort(yourList,Collections.reverseOrder(new LastLetterComparator()));
```

There are two different comparators to make it consistent you have to think about one that will be acceptable for your criteria.